# Gibberish when opening remote file with php

Tags: php, curl, encoding, utf-8, file-get-contents

I'm struggling to open this JSON file:
http://s.trustpilot.com/tpelements/1679763/f.jsonp

I tried with file_get_contents, fread, and cURL, and tried playing with utf8_encode, utf8_decode and iconv (my page encoding is UTF-8).

The thing is when I try to echo this string I get complete gibberish:
http://i.share.pho.to/340c6074_o.png

As you can see the file itself should display standard characters.

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you mind to post your complete code which fails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting gibberish because page is gzip'ed to save bytes. 
You can get with curl like this `curl --compressed http://s.trustpilot.com/tpelements/1679763/f.jsonp`.

Or add parameter to php curl extension. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");`

Comment: Amazing. Thanks a lot! Tell me, How can we determine if a page / file is gzipped?

Comment: Check this question http://superuser.com/questions/295360/how-to-know-if-a-site-is-gzipped. Generally response header tells you, to test curl -i http://s.trustpilot.com/tpelements/1679763/f.jsonp.